# Ingress gives 502 error

Tags: redirect, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

If I run through the [http load balancer example](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) it works fine in my google container engine project.  When I run "kubectl describe ing" the backend is "HEALTHY".  If I then change the svc out to one that points to my app as shown here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    name: app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    name: http
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    name: app
  type: NodePort
```

The app I'm running is django behind gunicorn and works just find if I make that a load balancer instead of a NodePort.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: app
    servicePort: 8000
```

Now when I run "kubectl describe ing" the backend is listed as "UNHEALTHY" and all requests to the ingress IP give a 502.

1. Is the 502 a symptom of the bad health check?
2. What do I have to do to make the health check pass?  I'm pretty sure the container running my app is actually healthy.  I never set up a health check so I'm assuming I have to configure something that is not configured, but my googling hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found the answer:
According to the requirements here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/cluster-loadbalancing/glbc#prerequisites the application must return a 200 status code at '/'.  Because my application was returning a 302 (redirect to login), the health check was failing.  When the health check fails, the ingress resource returns 502.

Comment: I think you can accept your answer. I face with  same problem and solved it via your approach. Thanks!

Comment: The URL doesn't need to be `/` - this can be configured with the `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` options on the pods. However, this must be configured before creating the ingress.

Comment: @kai, I tried that and it didn work for me unfortunately, even after recreating the ingress.

Comment: You saved my day thank you! But how do you handles login redirect?

Comment: I have no experience with this specifically, but I would imagine the key is in @kai 's comment.  Set the health check to use a dedicated health check url that users never visit so you can still have your redirect at `/`.

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to supplement the accepted answer with a more concrete explanation of why a health check on `/` is needed, even though `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` may be set up and working on the containers in the pods.

I had originally thought they were the same thing, but they're not.

The probes are used by the kubernetes engine to manage individual **containers** within a service. Whereas the health check on `/` is at the **service** level, and is part of the GCP *load balancer* contract. It's got nothing to do with kubernetes or containers per-se.

The reason it's needed with GKE is that the GCP load balancer is the default ingress controller. As stated in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#health_checks), by default the GCP load balancer requires backing services to return a `200` on `/` to check if they're live so it can manage which ones to route to.

If you want to configure this health check endpoint:

1. From GKE cluster version `1.17.6-gke.11` (*currently in beta*) you can configure it on the GCP load balancer. [See docs here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#direct_health).
2. Below `1.17.6-gke.11`, you *cannot* configure it on the GCP load balancer. It has to be a 200 on `/`. The only option to configure it would be to use a different, more configurable ingress controller like the nginx one. I haven't used this myself, so can't point to any specifics on that.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm reaching to the same conclusion. No matter what I my `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` says, my LB always finds the backends UNHEALTHY, because the backend `/` does not return `200`. It returns redirect. :|

Comment: *Possibly, if you use a different ingress controller, like the nginx one, you might be able to configure this.* .. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: @Nawaz I don't use the nginx controller so can't point you to anything specific on this, **but** the GCP load balancer is now configurable (from version `1.17.6-gke.11`).

Answer (score 1):

There are two kind of health checks

1. Kubernetes health checks
2. GKE (or GCP) ingress/loadbalancer health checks

**Kubernetes health checks**

Kubernetes uses liveness, readiness and startup probes to check the health of the containers.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

In web applications usually a path that returns a success code for a HTTP GET request is used in health check probes. Any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400 indicates success. Any other code indicates failure.

**GKE ingress/loadbalancer health checks**

According to the GCP documentation

> In GKE, an Ingress object defines rules for routing HTTP(S) traffic to applications running in a cluster. An Ingress object is associated with one or more Service objects, each of which is associated with a set of Pods. When you create an Ingress object, the GKE Ingress controller creates a Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancer and configures it according to the information in the Ingress and its associated Services. This load balancer supports multiple backend services on a single URL map. Each of the backend services corresponds to a Kubernetes Service, and each backend service must reference a Google Cloud health check. **This health check is different from a Kubernetes liveness or readiness probe because the health check is implemented outside of the cluster**.

GKE uses the following procedure to create a health check for each backend service corresponding to a Kubernetes Service:

- If the Service references a `BackendConfig` CRD with **healthCheck**
  information, GKE uses that to create the health check
- If the Service does not reference a `BackendConfig` CRD:

  - GKE can infer some or all of the parameters for a health check if the Serving Pods use a Pod template with a container whose readiness probe has attributes that can be interpreted as health check parameters( [see inferred parameters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#def_inf_hc) ). For this, the following conditions need to be satisfied

    - The readiness probe's port number must match the serving Pod's `containerPort`
    - The serving Pod's `containerPort` matches the Service's `targetPort`
    - The Service's `port` must match the Ingress object's `backend.servicePort`
  - If the Pod template for the Service's serving Pods **does not** have a container with a readiness probe whose attributes can be interpreted as health check parameters, the [default values](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#def_inf_hc) are used to create the health check

    - When using default values for the GKE health check, a HTTP GET request to `/` path must return 200 status code. So make sure to define the `/` of the application.
    - Even for use default values in health checks, Pod's `containerPort` , Service's `targetPort` and Ingress object's `backend.servicePort` must be matched. Also try to refer ports using port numbers instead of port names.

**Note:**

In Kubernetes health checks, any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400 consider as success. But In GKE ingress health checks only status code 200 consider as success. Due to this you may notice application has deployed and running fine but you get a 502.

Make sure application's health endpoints return 200 for **unauthenticated** requests. If authentication is enabled for health endpoints the request will be redirected and return a 300 status code.

Answer (score 0):

In our case external port and internalport are mentioned as 5000 in values.yaml , but service is listening on 3000 port ( came to know after seeing pod logs ) so 502 bad gateway has been displayed .

Once I updated external port and internal port to 3000 and upgraded the deployment of that particular service ,able to see required output .

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was not running ingress-controller pod, after cluster crash.
The easiest way to detect it is to list ingresses with

```
kubectl get ingress
```

Field address should be filled, in my case there was empty value

I listed pods for ingress-nginx namespace

```
kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
```

and found that pod not running

```
NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-controller-95db98cc5-rp5c4   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   218        18h
```

the reason was that pod scheduled to master node where port 80 is busy with external nginx.
I simply deleted pod with

```
kubectl delete pod nginx-ingress-controller-95db98cc5-rp5c4 -n ingress-nginx
```

and it reschedulled to worker node.
That's it. 502 error gone

Answer (score 0):

## AWS ALB Ingress: The case where Deployment POD terminates TLS/SSL

One thing that's important: If the backend is implemented completely with Self-signed CERTS and is the entity terminating TLS, the Ingress object MUST know that fact in order to have its healthcheck to work properly as the default healthcheck is HTTP. For example, AWS's ALB will needs to know that in order to properly verify its own Healthcheck.

- Verify if the Deployment, whose is being selected by the `NodePort` service, is terminating TLS/SSL (443, or any other port)
- If the pod itself has a healthcheck spec, it should include that.
- If there's no healthcheck specified in the POD, then you can verify if the ingress object is setting the proper protocol for the Ingress healthcheck itself.

  - For the case of AWS Ingress, it should use the annotations `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTPS`, and `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /`.

## Ingress

- For this example, the Deployment whose service forwards traffic to terminates TSL (The pod itself serves traffic with a self-signed cert).
- For this reason, the healthcheck on `/` must specify the correct protocol and path.

```yaml
# Example from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    # https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/annotations/
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: access_logs.s3.enabled=false
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:sa-east-1:806101772216:certificate/3db92ed3-5439-44e8-843d-fec0c9709501

    #### SOLUTION TO HTTPS Healthcheck From AWS ALB Ingress
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64264889/argo-workflows-ui-not-working-with-aws-ingress-controller/64268995#64268995
    # As the backend is implemented with certificates, it MUST include the healthcheck using HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
  name: argo-server-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: argoflows-my-server.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/*"
        backend:
          service:
            name: argo-server
            port:
              number: 2746
  tls:
  - hosts:
    secretName: argo-workflows-data-tls
```