# Argo workflows UI not working with AWS Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, argo-workflows, argoproj

I am trying to setup a AWS ALB Ingress on EKS. But the Argo UI is not working. But the port forwarding is working fine.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  name: admin-ns-endpoints
  namespace: admin
spec:
  rules:
  - host: argo-nonprod.sample.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: argo-server
          servicePort: 2746
        path: /*
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: xxxxxxx.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Getting 404 when accessing the endpoint.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: argo-server
  namespace: admin
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - server
        - --configmap=argo-workflow-controller-configmap
        env:
        - name: BASE_HREF
          value: /
        - name: IN_CLUSTER
          value: "true"
        - name: ARGO_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: argoproj/argocli:v2.9.3
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: argo-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2746
          name: web
          protocol: TCP
```

I used helm chart to deploy the chart.

I tried changing different values from in the ingress file but I am not successful.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try removing spec.rules.http.host? Aside, this works for us:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-alb-ingress
  namespace: argo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: aws-alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: access_logs.s3.enabled=false
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: REDACTED
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: REDACTED
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: REDACTED
  labels:
    app: nginx-service
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: argo-server
              servicePort: 2746
```

Comment: I think the point here is that the backend is implemented using HTTPS self-signed certs, correct @AlexanderCollins? Based on the fact that the ingress healthcheck is coming from AWS and needs to use HTTPS, we need to specify it on the metadata... That's why it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```yaml
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
```

My full config is:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ${name_http_ingress}
  namespace: ${namespace}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: argo-cd
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    # alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: 200,301,302,307
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.argogrpc: >-
      [{"field":"http-header","httpHeaderConfig":{"httpHeaderName": "Content-Type", "values":["^application/grpc.*$"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: >-
      {"type":"redirect","redirectConfig":{"port":"443","protocol":"HTTPS","statusCode":"HTTP_301"}}
    # external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: ${domain_name_public}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: ${domain_certificate}
    # alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: ${name_http_ingress}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    # alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip # require to enable sticky sessions ,stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds=60
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: load_balancing.algorithm.type=least_outstanding_requests
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-node-labels: ${tolerations_key}=${tolerations_value}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=${tags_env},Restricted=false,Customer=customer,Project=ops,Name=${name_http_ingress}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: routing.http2.enabled=true,idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=180

spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - ${domain_name_public}
  rules:
    - host: ${domain_name_public}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ssl-redirect
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
    - host: ${domain_name_public}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                # name: argo-cd-argocd-server
                name: argogrpc
                port:
                  number: 4433

          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: rnd-server-argo
                port:
                  number: 2746

          - path: /argo
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: argo-workwlow-server-argo
                port:
                  number: 2746
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to do below steps

**Step1: Configure below argogrpc service.**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/naguait85/argocd_helm-1/master/argocd-install/argogrpc.yaml

**Step2: Configure ingress using below ingress in argocd. change the hostname and certificate arn from aws public certificate.**

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/naguait85/argocd_helm-1/master/argocd-install/ingress.yaml