# AKS-AGIC setup getting 502 error after applying network policy

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have deployed two apps in the different namespaces and I don't want the pods deployed in one namespace to interact with the pods on the other namespace . I have applied the network policy, but after the application the backend shows as unhealthy on the app gateway and I am getting the 502 error and if i remove the policy i am able to reach the applications and backends are healthy on the application gateway.

I am using azure CNI
[image]

```
kind: NetworkPolicy 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
metadata: 
   app: app1 
    namespace: development 
  spec: 
    podSelector: 
      matchLabels: 
    ingress: []
```

Do i need to allow certain namespaces or pods in the policy ??

Answer (score 0):

> **To resolve the 502 error, try allowing below pods in the network
> policy:**

- Create a file named **`backend-policy.yaml`** as below and paste the following script in manifest. All inbound traffic to the pod is denied as no rules are defined under *ingress*.

```yaml
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: backend-policy
  namespace: development
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: yourwebapp
      role: backend
  ingress: []
```

- **Apply the network policy by using below command**:

```yaml
    kubectl apply -f backend-policy.yaml
```

> **If still the 502 error does not resolve, try the following workarounds:**

- Try ***checking NSGs*** associated with the azure application gateway. Ensure that communication to backend isn't blocked.
- Make sure to configure the port in ***BackendHttpSetting***.
- Make sure the configured port is open and check if there are any ***firewall rules*** blocking the traffic and disable them.

references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-network-policies#create-and-apply-a-network-policy

[Troubleshoot Bad Gateway errors - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502#:%7E:text=After%20configuring%20an%20application%20gateway%2C%20one%20of%20the,DNS%20is%20blocking%20access%20to%20backend%20pool%20members.).

[redirect - Ingress gives 502 error - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101808/ingress-gives-502-error?rq=1).

Comment: I have tested with the above file, i am still facing the problem. Actually I facing this problem only once i am applying this network policy else if i remove it I am able to connect to the app. I am not sure what to check the checkingNSG or BackendHttp setting